# Unable to launch chromium browser through docker in gauge/taiko framework and getting errors as Browser or page not initialized. Call `openBrowser()`

Tags: chromium, gauge

I am unable to launch the chromium browser through gauage/taiko framework and getting below errors. Please let me know to fix this issue?. TIA!

```
    Error: Browser or page not initialized. Call `openBrowser()` before using this API
    04-06-2021 22:53:38.540 [Gauge] [ERROR] Error Message: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
    [1889307:1889307:0604/225338.422772:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1390)] Unable to open X display.
    04-06-2021 22:53:38.540 [Gauge] [ERROR] Stacktrace: 
    Error: Failed to launch chrome!
    [1889307:1889307:0604/225338.422772:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1390)] Unable to open X display.
        at onClose (node_modules/taiko/lib/browserFetcher.js:282:11)
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (node_modules/taiko/lib/browserFetcher.js:268:11)
        at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
    04-06-2021 22:53:38.540 [Gauge] [ERROR] Error Message: Error: Browser or page not initialized. Call `openBrowser()` before using this API
    04-06-2021 22:53:38.540 [Gauge] [ERROR] Stacktrace: 
    Error: Browser or page not initialized. Call `openBrowser()` before using this API
        at validate (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:3442:11)
        at module.exports.closeBrowser (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:275:3)
        at module.exports.<computed> (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:3542:36)
        at Object.<anonymous> (ui/browser.js:24:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `headless:true` on openBrowser to run script in headless mode where GUI is not supported.

Comment: Thanks Par. Yes I have tried it and its not working.